# JQuery .width() returns significantly different width than displayed width

Tags: jquery, css, width

I'm attempting to calculate the width of a div that contains only text. Seems simple enough (I think.) The returned value is significantly different from the width shown in the Google Chrome Developer panel. I've attempted to search for an answer online, but am only seeing answers regarding outerWidth, innerWidth and problems with padding/margin/etc. I don't believe this to be the problem, but correct me if I'm wrong. I'll attach what I think is the relevant HTML, CSS and JS. I truly apologize if this is an ignorant question; I've tried my best to troubleshoot on my own. All of the width functions return the same value (even vanilla JS,) and the difference in values change depending on the length of text in the div. I'm happy to provide any further information if it's helpful!

HTML:

```
<div class='goal-cont'>
  <div id='goal-bar'>
    <div id="goal-progress"></div>
    <div id='title'></div>
    <div id='progress-text'>
      <span id='goal-current'>0</span>/<span id='goal-total'>0</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--<div id='goal-end-date'></div>-->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#title {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  //left: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

JS:

```
$('#title').html(obj.detail.title);
console.log($('#title').width());
```

And here are two images of the results I'm seeing (cannot attach images without 10 reputation):

Width shown in Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZkVW.png

Width calculated by JQuery: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUfOW.png

Answer (score 0):

I have found a fix to the problem. Apparently I was calling width too soon after it was set. Further calls down the line returned the correct value.